# How do couchdb curl commands translate to nano or node's http library?

Tags: node.js, http, curl, couchdb, couchdb-nano

Trying to use pouchdb and couchdb in a new app I’m building for a client and I’m getting desperate after struggling with what I assume are some of the most basic things. All instructions I find on couchdb are using curl commands and I can’t seem to be able to translate them into my application code. I’m using nodejs and express.

Specifically I'm struggling with these two questions, but a more general instruction on how translate curl instructions into my node app would probably be most helpful if it is possible.

How do I add a _security document with a member role to a database with nano or node’s http?
How do I add a role to an existing user with nano or node’s http?

Answer (score 0):

The PouchDB [API](https://pouchdb.com/api.html) is very easy to use. Most of the term used for PouchDB are similar to CouchDB.

As some of the feature of CouchDB are not implemented in the core PouchDB, some plugin exists.

For example, to use the _security : https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb-security